Why can't the Matplotlib library be installed on my system?
When I run command "pip install matplot" this error occur, I'm also working on it but can't understand the main Reason
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [22 lines of output]
  + meson setup C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38 C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38\.mesonpy-2c1zqfw9 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38\.mesonpy-2c1zqfw9\meson-python-native-file.ini
  The Meson build system
  Version: 1.5.1
  Source dir: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38
  Build dir: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38\.mesonpy-2c1zqfw9
  Build type: native build
  Program python3 found: YES
  Project name: matplotlib
  Project version: 3.9.1
  WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output
  
  ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  
  A full log can be found at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38\.mesonpy-2c1zqfw9\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried to get answer from chatgpt and follow complete step but waste of time.

With "pip install matplot" do you mean "pip install matplotlib"?  Note that your question is lacking information about which system you are running.  Maybe your environment doesn't work with pip? Did you check the documentation of your environment about installing new libraries? Are you sure Python is installed correctly?

It looks like pip can't find a suitable C compiler for the native code. Do you have one installed?

And no need to mention chatgpt unless you also want to mention your barber and your cat which are equally reliable for this type of thing.

Maybe Could not parse vswhere.exe output -- What am I doing wrong? also applies to your case?

In general python packages can be "source" or "binary". A source package will be compiled when it's installed, and requires that you have a compiler properly installed on your system. Binary packages are precompiled for specific platforms / python versions etc. In this case it appears that a binary package wasn't found so it's falling back to building from source - which is surprising because you appear to on windows and I would expect there to be a binary package for windows for most versions on Python.

But it would help if you include in the question what version of Python. Also you don't happen to have an arm rather than Intel machine by any chance?

Also note in the message A full log can be found at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_w4egfxf\matplotlib_a4133370be034e96b7676c177d0a4b38\.mesonpy-2c1zqfw9\meson-logs\meson-log.txt - it may help if you investigate if there's anything useful there

Is MS Visual C++ installed ?

The Windows wheels for the latest Matplotlib had problems so were deleted from PyPI. This is why pip was trying to build from source here. Because of the issue you saw, the whole release has now been yanked from PyPI. So if you try again, it should work and you will get v3.9.0. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/28660

I'm very Thankful to everyone all information helpfull for me. I'm a new Stackflow community member I don't know about this platform too much that's why by the way I resolve my issue Again Thanks

The official docs recommends installing it with --prefer-binary option, as:
pip install matplotlb --prefer-binary

This way, pip looks for the latest version of matplotlib for which a prebuilt wheel for your system exists.
